# html5 canvas in android

Tags: android, html, canvas, clicklistener

Is there any special way to get Android's browser to respond to click/press events? My code works fine in the popular browsers but when I use my Android tablet or Android phone, the nodes do not move when dragged/pressed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
#blurb_canvas {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0px;
  left: 150px;
} 
#blurb_data_holder {
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
} 
input.blurb_btn {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: solid 1px #c5c5c5;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 9em;
    height: 2em;
    padding: 5px;
} 
</style>
<body onLoad="init();">

    <table id="blurb_data_holder">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
            <input type="submit" title="" value="Data 1" id="data_1" class="blurb_btn" onClick="createBlurbNode(this.id);"/> <br />
            <input type="submit" title="" value="Data 2" id="data_2" class="blurb_btn" onClick="createBlurbNode(this.id);"/> <br />
            <input type="submit" title="" value="Data 3" id="data_3" class="blurb_btn" onClick="createBlurbNode(this.id);"/> <br />
            <input type="submit" title="" value="Data 4" id="data_4" class="blurb_btn" onClick="createBlurbNode(this.id);"/> <br />
            <input type="submit" title="" value="Data 5" id="data_5" class="blurb_btn" onClick="createBlurbNode(this.id);"/> <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>




    <canvas id="blurb_canvas">If you are able to see this message, your browser does not support HTML5's canvas feature.</canvas>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvasLay;
    var canvasContext;
    var blurbNodes;
    var x = 50;
    var y = 50;
    var movingObj = false;
    var movinganotherObj = false;
    var blurbSentences;

    function init(){
        canvasLay = document.getElementById('blurb_canvas');
        canvasContext = canvasLay.getContext('2d');
        canvasLay.width = window.innerWidth-150;
        canvasLay.height = window.innerHeight;

        blurbNodes = [];
        blurbNodes.push(new BlurbNode(300,75,60,1,1,'stuff here a'));
        blurbNodes.push(new BlurbNode(600,300,60,1,1,'stuff here b'));
        setInterval(drawScreen,25);
        canvasLay.addEventListener("mousedown", beginMovingObj, false);
        canvasLay.addEventListener("mousemove", moveObj, false);
        canvasLay.addEventListener("mouseup", stopMovingObj, false);
    }

    function createBlurbNode(text){
        blurbNodes.push(new BlurbNode(100,100,60,1,1,text));
    }

    function BlurbNode(positionx, positiony, radius, dx, dy, label){
        this.canvas = canvasLay;
        this.context = canvasContext;
        this.positionx = positionx;
        this.positiony = positiony;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
        this.label = label;
        this.moving = false;
        this.hasChild = false;
        this.hasParent = false;
    }

    BlurbNode.prototype.Create = function(){
        this.context.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.arc(this.positionx, this.positiony, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
        this.context.closePath();
        this.context.fill();
        this.context.fillStyle = '#000000';
        this.context.fillText(this.label,this.positionx-20,this.positiony);
    };

    function drawLineConnection(parentCenterx, parentCentery, childCenterx, childCentery){
        canvasContext.beginPath();
        canvasContext.fillStyle = '#000000';
        canvasContext.moveTo(parentCenterx, parentCentery);
        canvasContext.lineTo(childCenterx, childCentery);
        canvasContext.stroke();
    }

    function drawScreen(){  
        canvasLay.width = window.innerWidth-150;
        canvasLay.height = window.innerHeight;
        canvasContext.clearRect(0,0,screen.width,screen.height);

        for(i = 0; i<blurbNodes.length; i++){

            if(movingObj){
                if(!movinganotherObj && (x > blurbNodes[i].positionx-50 && x < blurbNodes[i].positionx+50) && (y > blurbNodes[i].positiony && y < blurbNodes[i].positiony+50)){
                    blurbNodes[i].moving = true;
                    movinganotherObj = true;
                }

                if(blurbNodes[i].moving && x < (canvasLay.width-60) && y < (canvasLay.height-60) && x > (60) && y > (60)){
                    blurbNodes[i].positionx = x;
                    blurbNodes[i].positiony = y;
                }
            }else{
                blurbNodes[i].moving = false;
            }

            if(!blurbNodes[i].hasChild && !blurbNodes[i].hasParent && !blurbNodes[i].moving && blurbNodes[i].positiony < canvasLay.height-60){
                blurbNodes[i].positiony = blurbNodes[i].positiony + blurbNodes[i].dy;
            }
            blurbNodes[i].Create();


            for(j = 0; j<blurbNodes.length; j++){
                if(blurbNodes[i] != blurbNodes[j] && 
                        Math.abs(blurbNodes[i].positionx - blurbNodes[j].positionx) < 150 &&
                        Math.abs(blurbNodes[i].positiony - blurbNodes[j].positiony) < 150){
                    drawLineConnection(blurbNodes[i].positionx, blurbNodes[i].positiony, blurbNodes[j].positionx, blurbNodes[j].positiony);
                    blurbNodes[i].hasChild = true;
                    blurbNodes[j].hasParent = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    function beginMovingObj(e) {
        movingObj = true;
    }
    function stopMovingObj(e) {
        movingObj = false;
        movinganotherObj = false;
    }
    function moveObj(e) {
        if(movingObj){
            x = e.pageX-150;
            y = e.pageY;
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggesting using jsfiddle so we can all see what your code is about and how its suppose to work. It always helps me when i know what im trying to fix. http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/qWgNj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/simonsarris/W45jt/

What you're missing really are the 'touchstart', 'touchmove', and 'touchend' events to compliment your mouse events.

You should really organize it better than I did, that was just the quickest code to get an example up and working.

Comment: Thanks. This actually works. The only problem now is that the response is really really slow. Have any ideas why this may be? Have you tried it on an android tablet or android phone?

Comment: In general I guess html5 is slow on Android devices? Maybe the frame rate?

Answer (score 0):

I adapted some code recently for drawing and needed to look a few places for the right event attributes. The following code works for me. Hopefully it will help you.

```
drawStart = function(ev) {
        if(ev.originalEvent.touches && ev.originalEvent.touches.length) {
            ev = ev.originalEvent.touches[0];
        } else if(ev.originalEvent.changedTouches && ev.originalEvent.changedTouches.length) {
            ev = ev.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
        }

        // Calculate the current mouse X, Y coordinates with canvas offset
        var x, y;
        x = ev.pageX - $(doodle.canvas).offset().left;
        y = ev.pageY - $(doodle.canvas).offset().top;
...
```

Comment: Can you give more details in the code on how to connect this to a canvas? Is this a listener function?

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is that your moveObj method isn't getting a good x and y. Add the first part of my code to make sure you have a good event to get them from. (my ev == your e). You might also need to listen to touchstart, touchmove, touchend in addition to your mouse events.

Comment: I don't think the issue is getting the wrong x,y coordinates. When I click on the canvas on my android devices the entire canvas highlights as if its embedded in the screen like an image or a button. But I'll take your advice and check a little later.